# Attribute must be enclosed in quotation marks

Tags: asp.net

When trying to build the solution, I am getting a warning, Attribute must be enclosed in quotation marks. How do I enclose the CommandArgument attribute in quotes ?

`<asp:LinkButton Runat="server" ID="lkAcknowledge" Visible="false"  CommandName="Acknowledge" CommandArgument=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AssignmentID")%> >Acknowledge</asp:LinkButton>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use single quotes:

`<asp:LinkButton Runat="server" ID="lkAcknowledge" Visible="false" CommandName="Acknowledge" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AssignmentID")%>'>Acknowledge</asp:LinkButton>`

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to use double quotes.

Comment: @stackuser Double quotes are not allowed because you need to be able to define strings from within the ASP Eval tag `<%# %>`, and the parser wouldn't be able to differentiate between `CommandArgument="..."` and `Eval("...")`. Fun fact of the day. :)

Answer (score 5):

Use single quotes:

```
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AssignmentID")%>'
```

Note you can also use the shorthand `Eval` since ASP.NET 2.0 to get rid of some of the noise:

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AssignmentID")%>'
```